# Changing variables while using recursive calls

Tags: c, arrays, recursion, boggle

I have the code below that solves a boggle game. It allows input of a dictionary.txt file, puts each line from the file into a linked list, then it allows input of a user inputted boggle game and attempts to solve it. I've gotten up to the point of solving it but now I'm a bit stuck. On my solve function I'm using recursive calls to try all the possible matches from the user input to see if its a word by taking one letter at a time, creating a word and comparing it to the dictionary.txt to see if its actually a word.

The problem I'm running into is keeping track of the letter's I've visited. Basically I'm recursively calling a 2d array that I've made, setting all the positions to 0 and changing it to 1 whenever I visit that position. **tl;dr How to change variables from a 2d array with recursive calls.**

Note: I have a lot of printf statements here solely for the purpose of debugging.

The bit of code I'm stuck on:

```
void wordChecker(struct trie* myDictionary, char boggleBoard[][4], char isThisAWord[], int i, int j, int x, int y, int tracker[][4]){
    printf("%d\n", tracker[i][j]);
    if (searchWord(myDictionary, isThisAWord, 0) == 1){
        printf("found a word in word checker %s", isThisAWord);
        return;
    }

    if (searchWord(myDictionary, isThisAWord, 0) == 0 && inBounds((i+DX[x]),(j+DY[y]))
                            && haveWeBeenHere(i+DX[x],j+DY[y], tracker)){

        strncat(isThisAWord, &boggleBoard[i+DX[x]][j+DY[y]], 1);
        printf("the board is on %c\n", boggleBoard[i+DX[x]][j+DY[y]]);
        printf("the current word %s\n", isThisAWord);

        ///I'm 100% sure its here that lies the problem, partly because I don't know what I'm doing.
        ///the tracker array isn't changing here and I'm sure its because I'm doing it wrong.
        i = i+DX[x];
        j = j+DY[y];
        tracker[i+DX[x]][j+DY[y]] = 1;
        x = -1;
        y = -1;
        wordChecker(myDictionary, boggleBoard, isThisAWord, i, j, x+1, y+1, tracker);
    } else if (x > 8)
        return;


   wordChecker(myDictionary, boggleBoard, isThisAWord, i, j, x+1, y+1, tracker);
    return;

}

int haveWeBeenHere(int i, int j, int tracker[][4]){
    if(tracker[i][j] == 0){
        tracker[i][j] == 1;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The whole code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct trie{
    int isWord;
    struct trie* nextLetter[26];
} trie;

const int DX_SIZE = 8;
const int DX[] = {-1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1};
const int DY[] = {-1, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1, 0, 1};

struct trie* initializer();
struct trie* insertWord(struct trie* myTrie, char word[], int num);
void freeDictionary(struct trie* myTrie);
int searchWord(struct trie* myTrie, char word[], int num);

int inBounds(int x, int y);
void wordChecker(struct trie* myDictionary, char boggleBoard[][4], char isThisAWord[], int i, int j, int x, int y, int tracker[][4]);

int main (){
    struct trie* myDictionary = initializer();
    int dictionarySize, i, j, boggleGames;
    char boggleBoard[4][4];

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("sampledictionary.txt", "r");
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &dictionarySize);
    for(i=0; i<dictionarySize; i++){
        char word[100];
        fscanf(fp, "%s", word);
        insertWord(myDictionary, word, 0);
    }

    scanf("%d", &boggleGames);
    for(i=0; i<4; i++)
        scanf("%s", boggleBoard[i]);

    char isThisAWord[16] = {0};
    for (i=0; i<4; i++){
        for(j=0; j<4; j++){
            int tracker[4][4] = {0};
            tracker[i][j] = 1;
            strncat(isThisAWord, &boggleBoard[i][j], 1);
            printf("copying %c\n", isThisAWord[0]);
            wordChecker(myDictionary, boggleBoard, isThisAWord, i, j, 0, 0, tracker);
        }
    }
/* debugger for dictionary.txt
    printf("search for? ");
    char word[100];
    scanf("%s", word);
    if (searchWord(myDictionary, word, 0) == 0){
        printf("%s is part of a word", word);
    }
    else if (searchWord(myDictionary, word, 0) == 1){
        printf("%s is a word in main");
    }
    else if (searchWord(myDictionary, word, 0) == 2){
        printf("%s is not a word", word);
    }
 */
    freeDictionary(myDictionary);
}

void wordChecker(struct trie* myDictionary, char boggleBoard[][4], char isThisAWord[], int i, int j, int x, int y, int tracker[][4]){
    printf("%d\n", tracker[i][j]);
    if (searchWord(myDictionary, isThisAWord, 0) == 1){
        printf("found a word in word checker %s", isThisAWord);
        return;
    }

    if (searchWord(myDictionary, isThisAWord, 0) == 0 && inBounds((i+DX[x]),(j+DY[y]))
                            && haveWeBeenHere(i+DX[x],j+DY[y], tracker)){

        strncat(isThisAWord, &boggleBoard[i+DX[x]][j+DY[y]], 1);
        printf("the board is on %c\n", boggleBoard[i+DX[x]][j+DY[y]]);
        printf("the current word %s\n", isThisAWord);


        i = i+DX[x];
        j = j+DY[y];
        tracker[i+DX[x]][j+DY[y]] = 1;
        x = -1;
        y = -1;
        wordChecker(myDictionary, boggleBoard, isThisAWord, i, j, x+1, y+1, tracker);
    } else if (x > 8)
        return;
    wordChecker(myDictionary, boggleBoard, isThisAWord, i, j, x+1, y+1, tracker);
    return;

}

int inBounds(int x, int y){
    if (x > 4 || x < 0 || y > 4 || y < 0)
        return 0;
    return 1;
}

int haveWeBeenHere(int i, int j, int tracker[][4]){
    if(tracker[i][j] == 0){
        tracker[i][j] == 1;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

struct trie* initializer(){
    struct trie* myTrie = malloc(sizeof(struct trie));
    myTrie-> isWord = 0;

    int i;
    for(i=0; i<26; i++)
        myTrie->nextLetter[i] = NULL;

    return myTrie;
}

struct trie* insertWord(struct trie* myTrie, char word[], int num){


    if (num == strlen(word)){
        myTrie->isWord = 1;
        return;
    }

    int nextIndex = word[num] - 'a';
    if(myTrie->nextLetter[nextIndex] == NULL)
        myTrie->nextLetter[nextIndex] = initializer();

    insertWord(myTrie->nextLetter[nextIndex], word, num+1);
}

int searchWord(struct trie* myTrie, char word[], int num){
int test = strlen(word);
    int nextIndex = word[num] - 'a';
    if (num == strlen(word))
        return myTrie->isWord;

    if (myTrie->nextLetter[nextIndex] == NULL)
        return 2;

    return searchWord(myTrie->nextLetter[nextIndex], word, num+1);
}

void freeDictionary(struct trie* myTrie){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<26; i++)
        if (myTrie->nextLetter[i] != NULL)
            freeDictionary(myTrie->nextLetter[i]);
    free(myTrie);
}
```

Comment: Can you reduce your code by some amount?

Comment: @silentboy Its a lot I know, sorry. If I had something like this tracker[i][j] = 1;
 recursiveFunction(i+1, j+1, tracker); and I recursively called it, would it change tracker? If not how would I go about it? Thats the bit I'm stuck on.

Comment: Leave only this really most important part of code in your post, please.

Comment: My compiler points out that the comparison `tracker[i][j] == 1;` in `haveWeBeenHere()` should be an assignment (as the comparison has no effect).  It also points out that `insertWord()` is supposed to return a value but the early `return;` does not, and neither does falling off the end of the function.  Since the return value is ignored, the function should be declared as returning `void` instead of `struct trie *`.